# Installing rails 4.1.1 on digital ocean vps using railsready results in version 2.x.x instead of 4.x.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've tried multiple ways to install rails on a digital ocean vps, but I keep getting what seems to be an older version of rails (2.x.x). I used railsready and rvm to install ruby and rails, and when I run rails -v I get 4.1.1. However, when I try to run the 4.x.x rails commands, it shows me this manual, which I believe is from an older version. I put in just the description, for simplicity:

```
Description:
The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

It seems to me this is from an older version of rails, I just do not understand why it is installing this version when it says it has installed 4.1.1. What could be causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Seems like it is the correct version to me.  The rails 2.x.x use something like `ruby script/server` 3 and onward use stuff like `rails server`.  What command are you trying to run?

Comment: I'm trying to get rails 4.1.0 installed with rails generate etc and everytime I try to install it I get the older version with script/generate

Comment: You use ```rails generate``` to create models, controllers, migrations after you create a new rails application.  If you want a new application called foo you would run ```rails new foo``` or if you wanted it in your current directory you would run ```rails new .```.  You can then use ```rails generate``` inside the new rails application folder.  See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html